# Getting conversion error QStyleOptionSpinBox to const QStyleOptionComplex*

Tags: c++, qt

I'm subclassing QSpinBox and trying to get the sub controls up/down arrows rectangle sizes as demonstrated here with python and pyside. However I get errors when trying to convert my code over to C++.

Here is working python example I'm trying to convert to Qt/C++

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class SuperSpinner(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SuperSpinner, self).__init__(parent)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionSpinBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        r = QtCore.QRect()
        for sc in (QtGui.QStyle.SC_SpinBoxUp, QtGui.QStyle.SC_SpinBoxDown):
            r= r.united(self.style().subControlRect(QtGui.QStyle.CC_SpinBox, opt, sc, self))
        if r.contains(event.pos()):
            self.setValue(0)
            self.selectAll()
        else:
            super(self.__class__, self).contextMenuEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SuperSpinner()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Error Message in Qt when attempting to compile
[image]

Main bits of CPP file:

```
#include "intsuperspinbox.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStyleOptionSpinBox>
#include <QCommonStyle>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QDebug>

IntSuperSpinBox::IntSuperSpinBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QSpinBox(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void IntSuperSpinBox::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
    opt.initFrom(this);

    // ERRORS HERE
    QRect upRect(this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, opt, QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp, this));

    QSpinBox::contextMenuEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Try using the style proxy(), `this->style()->proxy()->subControlRect(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [`QStyle::subControlRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#subControlRect) should be of type `QStyleOptionComplex*` so you need...

```
    QRect upRect(this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt, QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp, this));
```

Note `&opt` rather than simply `opt`.